# How to prevent inserting br on insertHtml automically on ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using `CKEDITOR.instances['desc'].insertHtml($preview);` where preview is equal to value `sometext&nbsp;` its inserting `sometext&nbsp;` in chrome but same code is adding `<br />` before `&nbsp` on mozilla (example: `sometext <br />&nbsp;`)

Answer (score 0):

You add this lines in config.js inside the `CKEDITOR.editorConfig`

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```